# Comparing the content of multiple data frames in R

Tags: r

In the scenario I have multiple data frames (~100, numbers may vary) but all with the same size. They are basically indicators and I need to take intersection of them all. See the following code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1=c("a","b","c","d"),col2=c(NA,NA,NA,NA),col3=c(NA,"X",NA,"X"),col4=c("X",NA,NA,"X"))
df2 <- data.frame(col1=c("a","b","c","d"),col2=c("X","X",NA,NA),col3=c(NA,NA,NA,"X"),col4=c(NA,NA,NA,NA))
df3 <- data.frame(col1=c("a","b","c","d"),col2=c(NA,NA,"X",NA),col3=c(NA,NA,NA,NA),col4=c(NA,"X",NA,NA))
```

What I need to create is the output data frame that would contain X if at least one data frame contained X in this cell:

```
output <- data.frame(col1=c("a","b","c","d"),col2=c("X","X","X",NA),col3=c(NA,"X",NA,"X"),col4=c("X","X",NA,"X"))
```

I can do this with nested loops but there must be some clever fast way to achieve this result.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3)
    index <- lapply(dfs, function(x) apply(x[,2:4], 1, function(y) all(is.na(y))))
    output2 <- list()
    for(i in 1:length(dfs)){
      output2[[i]] <- dfs[[i]][!index[[i]],]
    }
    output <- do.call(rbind, output)
```

Comment: If dfs is the vector containing the names of my data frames, then I get an error when running index line:
`Error in `[.default`(x, , 2:4) : incorrect number of dimensions`

Comment: dfs is list of dataframes. You can load them with dfs <- lapply(list.files(yourpath), read.csv)

Answer (score 0):

Say we start with an empty df whose columns we'll fill:

```
out <- data.frame(col1=c("a","b","c","d"), col2=NA, col3=NA, col4=NA)
```

Here's one way you could construct a single column with the desired property:

```
out$col2 <- sapply(1:nrow(out), function(r){
  ifelse(sum(!is.na(c(df1$col2[r], df2$col2[r], df3$col2[r]))) == 0, NA, "X")
})
```

So abstracting over the column, we could write a function like this:

```
make_output_column <- function(cname){
  sapply(1:nrow(out), function(r){
    values <- c(df1[[cname]][r], df2[[cname]][r], df3[[cname]][r])
    ifelse(sum(!is.na(values)) == 0, NA, "X")
  })
}
```

And then apply it across all the columns we want to construct, to create the desired output:

```
cols <- c("col2", "col3", "col4")
out[, cols] <- lapply(cols, make_output_column)

## col1 col2 col3 col4
##    a    X <NA>    X
##    b    X    X    X
##    c    X <NA> <NA>
##    d <NA>    X    X
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to provide a list of data frames instead of listing them explicitly in this line of code:
`values <- c(df1[[cname]][r], df2[[cname]][r], df3[[cname]][r])`

Comment: certainly! yep, where `df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)`, you could use `sapply(df_list, function(df) df[[cname]][r])` (maybe set `USE.NAMES=FALSE` in sapply call too)

Comment: @scyth See my post as well as the post that I link to in order to get a more extensible method for putting data.frames into a list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a technique with `do.call` and `pmax`

```
# put your data.frames into a list
myList <- mget(ls(pattern="df\\d"))
```

See my answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames) for more details on this line.

```
cbind(myList[[1]][1], do.call(function(...) pmax(..., na.rm=TRUE),
                              lapply(myList, "==", "X"))[, 2:4])
  col1 col2 col3 col4
1    a    1   NA    1
2    b    1    1    1
3    c    1   NA   NA
4    d   NA    1    1
```

Here, `myList[[1]][1]` pulls off the first column from one of the data.frames in the list to return a data.frame with a single column. You could equivalently use `df[1]`. `lapply(myList, "==", "X")` runs through the list of data.frames and returns values of TRUE and FALSE for if X is included a cell in the data. Then `do.call` uses `pmax` to return the maximum value of each cell for the list of TRUEs and FALSEs and NAs.

If its super important to have "X"s instead of 1s, then follow this with

```
dat[dat == 1] <- "X"
```